# Why can't I delete an object before replacing it with a new one?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, object, pointers

I have a 2D array of object pointers of type `Organism`, which is declared like this `Organism*** organisms;` and I have a function that replaces one object in this array with another. This is how I tried to write this function:

```
void World::SetOrganism(Organism * org, const Position & pos) {
    if (pos.x < width && pos.x >= 0 && pos.y < height && pos.y >= 0) {
        delete organisms[pos.x][pos.y];
        organisms[pos.x][pos.y] = org;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling the function:

```
world.SetOrganism(new EmptyTile(this->position, world), this->position);
```

`EmptyTile` inherits from `Organism`.

The problem is that I alway get this error `Exception thrown: read access violation. this->organisms was 0x79E5D62E.` on the line with `delete`. I'm still learning C++, am I not supposed to delete this object to avoid a memory leak?

EDIT:
This is how I'm allocating `organisms`:

```
World::World(const int& height, const int& width) {
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;

    organisms = new Organism * *[width];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        organisms[i] = new Organism * [height];
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            Position* pos = new Position(i, j);
            organisms[i][j] = new EmptyTile(*pos, *this);
            delete pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be sure that `organisms` array was properly initialised with `nullptr` (zeroes). If not, then of course, deleting item will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: What does `organisms[pos.x][pos.y]` currently point when you decide to `SetOrganism()` a new one? Does it already point to something that you can actually `delete` (i.e., either `nullptr` or another object that was created via `new`)!?

Comment: It's filled with objects created using `new`.

Comment: How are you allocating `organisms`?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Edited the question.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: What does your `EmptyTile` do with the `Position` that it is given at initialization? Just asking because you're deleting that right afterwards…

Comment: I'm assigning it to a `Position position` inside the `EmptyTile` using initializer list. I'm assuming that it creates a copy of it so deleting the `pos` should be fine, right?

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::shared_ptr<Organism>` to help with memory management, and `std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Organism>>>` rather than raw allocation of the array. Oh, and `new EmptyTile(Position(i, j), *this)`.

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks for the advice, but I still would like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I've stared at this long enough to conclude that your bug is in code you haven't shown yet.

Comment: The error message indicates that your `organisms` array has been corrupted by somewhere before you call `SetOrganism`.  Try running your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to see if/where you are corrupting memory.